# If a cubic has a constructable root $a$, then $a$ is either rational or in some number field $Q(\sqrt{r})$ For some $r$ belongs to the rationals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I know that if a polynomial has a constructible root, then it must have a rational root. Thus I try to prove it in two cases:
If $a$ is the rational root, then we are done. However, if $a$ is not the rational root, how do I show that $a$ must be in $Q(\sqrt{r})$ rather than $Q(\sqrt{r})(\sqrt{s})$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a cubic polynomial $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ has a root it must have a minimal polynomial less then $3$.
The constructible numbers only contain minimal polynomials of degrees which are powers of $2$.
the only two powers of two under $3$ are $1,2$.
Option 1:
if the polynomial can be reduced into 3 linear factors then we are done.
Option 2:
if the polynomnial can be factored into a linear and quadratic factor then the quadratic factor is the root of $x^2+ax+b$, $\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}$ which is a part of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{a^2-4b}]$.